# Visual Studio version to install Scrapy

Tags: python, visual-studio, scrapy, pip, easy-install

I am new to using Python and am trying to install Scrapy using pip and easy_install. Currently I am getting the "could not find vcvarsall.bat" error.

From using Google I found that I need some version of Microsoft Studio, preferrably the 2008 one.

However, I do not quite understand the differences between those three options:

- Redistributable version - only installs runtime components, no coding/building environment?
- Express version - some part of the building environment?
- Visual Studio - the whole thing?

Is the redistributable sufficient to install scrapy using pip or easy_install? Or what exactly do I need?

Comment: Try installing first Python(x,y) distribution: https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/. Then use pip from there to install Scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

Since scrapy is pure python this error is from easy_install trying to build one of the extensions - the way to fix this is to install the windows builds of the extensions required **first** - see the list [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install-platform-notes).

To answer the other part of your question the versions mentioned are:

1. Redistributable - the files needed on any machine to run code built with VS-2008.
2. Express - The free but limited in both what it will do and what you are allowed to do.
3. Full - Without the limitations but you may well have to pay for it.

To run python you already have 1.  Eitehr 2 or 3 can build extensions for python but are not needed for pure python, see the first bit of the above, and you can often find pre-built versions of the extension libraries.